# Looking for application that generates INSERT statements for data in table(s)

Tags: sql-server, desktop-application, configuration-management

Looking for an application that allows me to connect to an SQL Server, select any number of tables, and then generate INSERT statements for the data contained in these tables.

Anyone knows of such an app? Preferably freeware but commercial versions could be interesting as well.

Thanks,
Bruce

Answer (score 3):

Here's an [interesting SPROC](http://vyaskn.tripod.com/code.htm#inserts) that seems like it would do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to take a look at Microsoft SQL Server Database Publishing Wizard 1.1 (http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=56E5B1C5-BF17-42E0-A410-371A838E570A&displaylang=en). From the description:

> SQL Server Database Publishing Wizard enables the deployment of SQL Server databases into a hosted environment on either a SQL Server 2000 or 2005 server. It generates a single SQL script file which can be used to recreate a database (both schema and data) in a shared hosting environment where the only connectivity to a server is through a web-based control panel with a script execution window.

Comment: Good tool, would be better if you could select which tables to script though, instead of the 'all or nothing' approach..

Comment: Agree, this was a close shot but I also would prefer if I could select which objects to script. I'll use it for now though.

Answer (score 1):

Try [SSMS Tools Pack](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/). It's free and has many other enhancements for Sql Server Management Studio.

Comment: This seemed to be something that would suit my needs fine. Unfortunately I get an exception when lauching SSMS Express after install and the tool pack options is nowhere to be seen. :(

Answer (score 0):

The [EMS DB Extract for SQL Server](http://www.sqlmanager.net/en/products/mssql/extract) product is commercial and you'd have to check their site for pricing, will create SQL scripts with INSERT statements of data from selected tables.

Of course the software will do much more, but it will also do what you want.